# Hiding a column of table with a class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to hide the first column of the table. If i remove col-id class then it works fine but i can't remove that class.

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.marks.length; i++) {
    var col_id = result.marks[i].col_id;
    var student_id = result.marks[i].student_id;
    var roll_no = result.marks[i].roll_no;
    var first_name = result.marks[i].first_name;
    var last_name = result.marks[i].last_name;
    var secured_marks = result.marks[i].secured_marks;

    $("#marks-table tbody").append('<tr></tr>');
    $("#marks-table tbody tr:last").append('<td class="col-id" hidden>' + col_id + '</td>');
    $("#marks-table tbody tr:last").append('<td hidden>' + student_id + '</td>');
    $("#marks-table tbody tr:last").append('<td>' + roll_no + '</td>');
    $("#marks-table tbody tr:last").append('<td>' + first_name + '</td>');
    $("#marks-table tbody tr:last").append('<td>' + last_name + '</td>');
    $("#marks-table tbody tr:last").append('<td class="secured-marks">' +
        '<input type="text" class="form-control text-center secured-marks-input" value="' + secured_marks + '"></td>');
}
```

Comment: <td class="col-id" hidden>  should be ; <td class="col-id hidden">

Comment: Only add tags that are relevant to your question please. I can't see any PHP or MySQL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide a `<td>` you can just do

```
<td style="display:none;">
```

Thus, in your code, you can just do

```
$("#marks-table tbody tr:last").append('<td class="col-id" style="display:none;">' + col_id + '</td>');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with Jquery, you can use selectors, like this :

```
$('#marks-table tr td:first-child').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the css of "col-id":

```
.col-id{
    display: none;
}
```